# Random Forest with R. cannot allocate vector of size 7.5 Gb

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

i have a dataset (df) with 10000 tweet with 2 observations (body and label); The first 4000 tweets are labelled(positive or negative) and i want to use it as training set to predict the label of the rest of the tweets ,testing, according to the text body.
I want to use Random Forest algorithm in order to predict(caret package) and cross validation to determine the accuracy.
i used this script:

```
training <- subset(df[1:4000,])
testing  <- subset(df[4001:10000,])

fitControl1 <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                       number = 10,
                       repeats = 10)

rfFit <- train(training$label~ training$body, data = training, 
             method = "rf", 
             trControl = fitControl,
             verbose = FALSE)
```

But this is the error from the console

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.5 Gb
```

How can i fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052436/does-random-forest-in-r-have-a-limitation-of-size-of-training-data

Answer (score 5):

The random forest algorithm can destroy your memory, especially if you do not have a lot of it. R can use disk as memory though, so this will probably help you.

If you check

```
memory.limit()
```

It will show you the size of your memory. However you can also use this command to set it.

```
memory.limit(100000)
```

There you go, now you have ~100GB of memory. Of which a bunch is on your hard drive.

If you don't have much hard drive space... well this won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Random Forest will try to allocate your observations within trees of possibilities among the variables or features. But there is something weird the way you are doing it. If you have one variable for the body of the tweet (a string of the tweet) and the second is the label. There is no actual features to perform the classification and the random forest would try to memorize (overfit) the training set. The random forest algorithm creates several trees of possibilities to create a compound model, which yield in a huge space of possibilities, specially if you did not extract the features from your corpus of tweets (which is what I think you are doing), and the model would behave really poorly.

What you need to do is tokenize the body of the tweets to create a model for extract the features of the corpus. I recommend the [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) for extracting text features. It is ok if you don't know python, the explanation is very explicit and you would find the tools to perform the operations in R.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the complete tweet as one variable(class character), while training the model R will first convert the character vector into factors(since statistical model can be build around numeric matrix not characters) and while converting each tweet into one factor it will require such huge space, please refer this [blog](http://tusharramanblog.com/2018/05/04/error-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-26-6-gb/).
Also, this is a problem of NLP. And before building the model I would recommend you to first tokenise the dataset and make a sparse matrix.